# XML parsing error in AJAX response from a servlet

Tags: ajax, servlets

I am using AJAX for validation. I am using servlet in server side.I am writing in the response as follows

```
response.setContentType("text/xml");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        out.write("<valid>true</valid>");
```

And I am getting the response as follows

```
 var message = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("valid")[0];
            alert(message.value);
```

But I am getting a error:

> XML parsing error: no element found
>
> Location: moz-nullprincipal:{0ccce530-8dbe-4754-99a4-5d0f12484d56}
>
> Line Number 1, Column 1:.

I don't know what is the problem can anyone help, please?

Comment: Are you using the right mime type? Is it not application/xml?

Comment: @doc_180 No I am not using mime.

Comment: setContentType is setting the response's mime type. :) same thing. 'text/xml' is the correct type though, depending on what type/class xmlhttp really is though.

Comment: My bad, text/html is fine. Could you try debugging using firebug? Are you getting the correct response. It either has to be wrong mime type or xml is not formed properly.

Comment: @doc_180:I got the above mentioned error in firebug XML page

Comment: Obviously this error is caused by parsing. could you split the declaration so that you have a var that stores responsexml? That will help understand the response format.

Comment: @doc_180 I think the problem is with the server side part have a look at that part check whether there is any mistake in that one cos it is returning null value.